# The object-fit property didn't work on my carousel image

Tags: css, html, carousel

I'm using bootstrap 4 and have a code below, i try to make the position of any image which will putted inside are getting fitted on my own margin. So i try to use "object-fit" property in my css document. But it doesn't work at all, can i have other solution?

```
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100 cover" src="assets/images/cover_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h5>This is cover 1</h5>
                <p>and this is the captions</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/image2.png" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block d-md-block out">
                    <h5>This is cover </h5>
                    <p>and this is the caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/cover_3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-block d-md-block">
                    <h5>This is cover </h5>
                    <p>and this is the caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

There in the class **.carousel-inner** i put the *object-fit:cover*, but it was not giving any effect on my images

Comment: Can you put a working example here in codepen or something else, please?

Comment: Oke here is some : https://codepen.io/muttaqin_yasis/pen/YbpGmY
the objectives for me is to make all the picture fit my margin in carousel-inner class

Comment: I found that you added  `object-fit:center;`  in `.carousel-inner`. Which is invalid. Can you try to add `object-fit:cover;` in the images?